# Possibilidade de deletar commit

Tags: versionamento, svn

Dei um commit porém usando uma versão do visual studio diferente da que o projeto foi feita, sendo assim ocorrerão problemas na publicação. Gostaria de saber se tem como eu apagar esse commit feito, sendo que ninguém deu update ainda, pra poder baixar a versão do projeto no VS correto, fazer as alterações e realizar um novo commit? Estou usando o `AnkhSVN`.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Você pode reverter o `último` commit que você fez, da seguinte forma:

- Digite `svn log -v -r M:N [--stop-on-copy] PATH`
- Copie o `Path` do último commit feito (e.g: `6b955d0`)
- Digite `snv revert -v path` para desfazer as alterações feitas (e.g: `git revert -n 6b955d0`)
- As alterações foram desfeitas, agora você pode dar um novo commit com as alterações antigas

Para um pouco mais de detahes sobre o comando visite:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.revert.html

Comment: Ele não está utilizando o git @Lucas Bittencourt.

Comment: Não estou utilizando o GIT.

Comment: A resposta já foi editada pelo Brewerton usando o svn. 